# how to push in array object with usestate in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use `useState` to fill data in array object but it not working with `setSharhItems([... , {new item}]`.

The code does not have errors, but the data is not correctly pushed into the array.

I use from react version `"react": "^16.14.0"`. I am confused why not working.

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export const Expense = () => {

const [sharhItems, setSharhItems] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() =>
        { 
            GetAllSoratHazineSharh() 
        }
    , []);

    axios(
      {
        url: `http://192.168.0.254:3333/api/DOTMobileApi/GetAllSouratHazineSharh?mohitId=${user.lastMohitID}&sharh=${"11111"}`,
        method: "get",
        headers:
        {          
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access-tocken")}`,       
        }
      }).then(function (response) {

          const resultItems = response.data;
          console.log("resultItems: ")
          console.log(resultItems) //  it return data with correctly
          
          resultItems.map((data, index) => {        

          setSharhItems( [...sharhItems,
            {
              code_Hesab: data.code_Hesab,
              item_ID: data.item_ID,
              item_Title_text: data.item_Title_text,
              markaz1: data.markaz1,
              markaz2: data.markaz2,
              markaz3: data.markaz3
            }]
          );  // not working correctly

         
          setSharhItems(oldArray => [...oldArray,
          {
            code_Hesab: data.code_Hesab,
            item_ID: data.item_ID,
            item_Title_text: data.item_Title_text,
            markaz1: data.markaz1,
            markaz2: data.markaz2,
            markaz3: data.markaz3
          }]); // not working correctly         
        });

        console.log("sharh items: ");
        console.log(sharhItems);  
       
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log("axois error: ");
        console.log(error)
      })

  }

  return (<h1>test</h1>)
}
```

Comment: The exios call should be inside a `useEffect`. Otherwise every re-render will trigger another request, which will then cause more renders, and create a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong way to fetch HTTP in the top level of a hooks component.

You need to use [useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects) to request or [react-query hooks](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/overview).

While you setState in **then** callback function and react will render the component and re-request this HTTP and program will fall in a loop.

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export const Expense = () => {

const [sharhItems, setSharhItems] = useState([]);
    const getAllSoratHazineSharh = ()=>{

      axios(
        {
          url: `http://192.168.0.254:3333/api/DOTMobileApi/GetAllSouratHazineSharh?mohitId=${user.lastMohitID}&sharh=${"11111"}`,
          method: "get",
          headers:
          {          
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access-tocken")}`,       
          }
        }).then(function (response) {
  
            const resultItems = response.data;
            console.log("resultItems: ")
            console.log(resultItems) //  it return data with correctly
            
            resultItems.map((data, index) => {        
  
            setSharhItems( [...sharhItems,
              {
                code_Hesab: data.code_Hesab,
                item_ID: data.item_ID,
                item_Title_text: data.item_Title_text,
                markaz1: data.markaz1,
                markaz2: data.markaz2,
                markaz3: data.markaz3
              }]
            );  // not working correctly
  
           
            setSharhItems(oldArray => [...oldArray,
            {
              code_Hesab: data.code_Hesab,
              item_ID: data.item_ID,
              item_Title_text: data.item_Title_text,
              markaz1: data.markaz1,
              markaz2: data.markaz2,
              markaz3: data.markaz3
            }]); // not working correctly         
          });
  
          console.log("sharh items: ");
          console.log(sharhItems);  
         
        }).catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log("axois error: ");
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
    useEffect(() =>
        { 
            getAllSoratHazineSharh() 
        }
    , []);



  return (<h1>test</h1>)
}
```